# Dnn Error with Custom Errors Off Still not Showing Error

Tags: web-config, dotnetnuke, custom-errors

**Background**:

I had setup a DNN 7.0 test environment and built a couple of custom modules.  On my third custom module, I finished setting it up using Chris Hammond's template and followed the instructions provided with the template (I did this for the previous modules as well with no issue).  After installing the module, my site won't work.  All I get on every page is DotNetNuke Error with no additional information.

**Problem:**

Obviously something went wrong with my module install, but I am completely helpless to find out what.  All I get is a non-descript error message provided by DNN.  I've set modified my Web config to the following:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

But I'm still getting the generic "DotNetNuke Error" message.  I need to see stack trace and any other information to see where my error is spawning.  Is there another way to do this with DNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, I've just been running SQL commands against the EventLog table.  You can get collated information on the error message from there and the stack trace and other information can be found in the LogProperties field.

It appears my module created the infamous "DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.GetSkin(Me)" error found [here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/111/threadid/317776/scope/posts.aspx).  Unfortunately my situation appears to be somewhat different as the only recommended solution does not work for me.  Looks like it's time for another DNN wipe.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a weird Virtual Directory on the Desktopmodules folder, or a folder within that.

I've had a few problems in my testing where IIS would turn that into a virtual directory and cause problems, but not something I could reproduce at will.

Also, check out the latest release of the templates for DNN7

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue ever since I've started using the new DNN 7 templates, has something to do with the way I'm debugging the modules.

The following fixed the issue:

- Delete the virtual directories under the desktop modules
- Restart IIS